# Wrong IP address using telize in a rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ip

In my rails app I'm using telize to get the user's IP.

```
ip = RestClient.get "http://www.telize.com/ip"
```

When I push my app to heroku the IP I get back from telize is 54.80.42.162 instead of 204.197.207.32 (which is my actual correct IP).  I assume this is related to the fact that the app is hosted on Heroku.  Can someone help me in figuring this out or suggest another way to get the user's IP address?

Thanks.